# Remove Don't Destroy On Load

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi I'm making a pizza menu based game and I have many objects in my menuCard scene where they have Don't destroy on load attached to it so that I can move them to the next screen but when I want to come back to the menuCard scene I don't want the object which have don't destroy on load attached

Menu Card => Where all my items are
scene 1 =>   where I want to move them to next screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have an object in Unity 3D that stays in scenes and does not recreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52285514/how-to-have-an-object-in-unity-3d-that-stays-in-scenes-and-does-not-recreate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the approach is to keep references on DontDestroyOnLoad instances and remove duplicates at creation time. Just add that script to object in scene which you want to be dont destroyable and set the unique id in the inspector field.

```cs
    public class DontDestroyOnLoad : MonoBehaviour 
    {
        [SerializeField] string _id;

        public static DontDestroyOnLoad Get(string id)
        {
            var instances = FindObjectsOfType<DontDestroyOnLoad>();
            return instances.FirstOrDefault(i => i._id == id);
        }

        void Awake()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_id))
            {
                _id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            }

            var instance = Get(_id);

            if (instance != null && instance != this)
            {
                Destroy(instance.gameObject);
            }
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject) ;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to unset DontDestroyOnLoad.  Split them off into their own scene and load them separately from the menuCard Scene in the in first place.